# Haskell Iterate If Condition is False

Tags: haskell

I have a set of numbers. For example `set = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8]`. I need to write a loop, that will only choose elements that are in total for example smaller than `max = 30`.

```
for(int i = 0;i<set.length();i++) { total = total + set[i]; if (total <= max) return i; }
.....
elements are from 0 to returned index
```

I have no idea how to do it recursively in haskell using only one cycle.

Comment: What does "only one cycle" mean?  If you mean a single traversal of the list, are you sure that's necessary if you take advantage of laziness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walk down the list, emitting elements until their total is too big. So:

```
thePriceIsRight max (x:xs) | x <= max = x : thePriceIsRight (max-x) xs
thePriceIsRight _ _ = []
```

In ghci:

```
> thePriceIsRight 30 [1,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: This is nicer with `scanl`, isn't it? `thePriceIsRight max = takeWhile (<= max) . scanl (+) 0`. edit: actually I see it is asking for the items themselves, not the cumulative sums. Okay, maybe not so easy to use `scanl`.